# there's an error in your program: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm using this version
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

so, i have a problem here

```
with open(ntpserverfile) as f:
     ntplist = f.readlines()
```

'open' and 'as' have a redlight if i press F5 for run, im searching how fix that but im a newbie at python, someone can help me ?

Comment: What's directly above those two lines in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` statements must be enabled manually in Python 2.5, and they don't exist at all in lower versions. To enable them, put the following [future statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) at the top of any file you want to use `with` statements in, after the `#!` line:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

(Specifically, the only things that can come above it are comments, the module docstring, blank lines, and other future statements.)

Comment: Thanks Worked but now i receive a new error "ImportError: No module named scapy.all"
i already installed the scapy a 2 hours ago

Comment: @Red'Skull': That's an entirely different question. I recommend you try to solve it yourself; if you find yourself unable to, post a new question.